# Backup AWS VOLUME to S3 (not EBS Snapshot on s3)

Tags: amazon-web-services, backup, amazon-s3

## Backup AWS #Volume (to #S3 or similar).

Problem:
I have some old instances, and even worse, old data volumes, that needs to be stored for some time, then removed. Very likely noone would look at it again.

Problem:
EBS costs (per TB) - 110$
EBS Snapshot - 55$
S3 IA storage -  **12,5$**

90% cheaper!

Is there any reasonable way to backup this to S3 other than mounting the volumes and dd (bit-copy) manually?

Comment: EBS Snapshots are compressed and to some extent deduplicated against others, so you should look at your cost and usage billing detail records to see how much these snapsnots *actually* cost.  At last check, my actual snapshot charges were a small fraction of what you would anticipate if you assumed a snapshot of a 100 GB volume consumes 100 GB of snapshot storage.  It doesn't.

Comment: If you want to access the data on the EBS volume you need to mount it. I wouldn't backup using dd, I'd probably just upload the useful data to S3, perhaps in a zip file. I wouldn't do anything with a boot volume, too much risk of not being able to boot it again.